# Why is sort by name reverse alphabetical?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, users, sort

It makes sense that reputation or date should sort descending, but name?  I tested both [/users](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users?filter=a&sort=name) and [/tags](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/tags?filter=a&sort=name) and they sort reverse alphabetical, so Z before A.  Is that by design or just a side effect of the default sorting being reputation in descending order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its by design.  Default `order` is descending across the board, this includes lexicographic sorts.

Comment: I kinda like it better that way :)

Comment: It struck me as odd on names, but I can accept it is by design I suppose.

Comment: @Jim - if you want the "normal" ordering, just set `order=asc` in the request.